# Toggle enable/disable input button if one or more checkboxes are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small piece of code that I want to use as a condition for a jQuery dialog.  Pretty simple case, if checkboxes are checked, enable button, if not, disable it.  The below code disables the button just fine, but does not enable it when checking any checkboxes.

I tried multiple variations and I cannot get this to work in my code (several work fine in Fiddle).  Many thanks for your help.

**JS snippet**

```
if (button.text() == "Apply") {
    if ($("selectLocation").is(':checked'))
        button.enabled(true); // checked
    else
        button.enabled(false);  // unchecked
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selectLocation" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use Jquery's .prop() to solve this one

```
if (button.text() == "Apply"){
    if ($("selectLocation").is(':checked')){
        button.prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else{
        button.prop('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

I have never been able to get .attr() to work for this situation

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$("input[name=selectLocation]")
```

It's not working because you are selecting element with tag `selectLocation` not element with name `selectLocation`

Answer (score 0):

if button is a jquery element:

```
button.attr("disabled", "disabled"); //to disable it
button.removeAttr("disabled"); //to reenable it
```

In your code, it should be:

```
if (button.text() == "Apply") {
    if ($("selectLocation").is(':checked'))
        button.removeAttr("disabled"); //to reenable it
    else
        button.attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

The selector `$("input[name=selectLocation]")` should work

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if jQuery is going to select the name like that, add in an ID and change the selector.

```
if (button.text() == "Apply") {
    if ($("#selectLocation").is(':checked'))
        button.removeAttr("disabled");
    else
        button.attr("disabled", "disabled");
}

<input id="selectLocation" type="checkbox" name="selectLocation" />
```